# how to make row alignment in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make alignment in row if I give space in between spaces occupies between widgets, but I need to get two text at the left and another one in the right. How to do it?

```dart
Row(
    // mainAxisAlignment:
    // MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Icon(Icons.comment),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text(snapshot.data![index].comments.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
      )
    ]),
```

check the image in the description

[image]

Comment: You want to above image like design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
 Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("6",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Text("Aug 4,2021"),
              ),
            )
          ])
```

**OR**

```
      Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment:
          // MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("6",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Text("Aug 4,2021"),
              ),
            )
          ])
```

**OR**

```
      Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment:
          // MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text("6",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text("Aug 4,2021")
          ])
```

**FullCode:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // testIt();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Mainwidget()));
}

class Mainwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mainwidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainwidgetState createState() => _MainwidgetState();
}

class _MainwidgetState extends State<Mainwidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var richText = RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: '*',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)));
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          height: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0,vertical: 8),
                child: Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment:
                  // MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Wrap(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text("6",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: Text("Aug 4,2021"),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Row buildRow2() {
    return Row(
                // mainAxisAlignment:
                // MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text("6",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Aug 4,2021")
                ]);
  }

  Expanded buildExpanded() {
    return Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text("6",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below code hope its help to you. You can used **[Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)** class for that

```
 Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Icon(Icons.comment),
        ),
        Text('6'),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text('Aug 4, 2021'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Spacer()** for this purpose, like this:

```
Row(
children:[
  Text("TEXT 1"),
  Text("TEXT 2"),
  Spacer(),
  Text("TEXT 3"),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Expanded` widget.

```
Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.comment),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                    snapshot.data![index].comments
                        .toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontWeight:
                        FontWeight.bold)),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Text(snapshot
                  .data![index].date
                  .toString()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.comment),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                snapshot.data![index].comments.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
      ],
    ),
```

I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.. result in pic you can decore your's[image]

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10,left:10),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20),
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
              
                children:[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: const [
                        Icon(Icons.settings),
                        Icon(Icons.settings)
                      ]
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child:Text('00:00'),
                  ),
                  
                ],
                
              ),
            ), 
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward way to do:

**flutter center row:**

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center //Center Column contents vertically,
```

**flutter float right**

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 120.0,
    width: 120.0,
    color: Colors.blue[50],
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: FlutterLogo(
        size: 60,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```